# Incrementing a 2D array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, increment, pre-increment

I have just started learning 2D arrays in C and I came across this code where a 2D array is directly pre-incremented like this `++array`.

I tried to print the matrix in 3 different places(After initializing, in function after increment, in main function after function call), but I can't understand how the pre-incrementation works.

I also noticed that `a[1][1]++` is reflected in the original matrix(8 is incremented to 9) but nothing else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printmatrix(int[3][3]);
int function(int a[][3])
{
    int i,j;
    ++a; //what does this do?
    printf("In function...\n");
    printmatrix(a);
    a[1][1]++;
}
void printmatrix(int a[3][3])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
printf("Initially...\n");
printmatrix(a);
function(a);
printf("In main...\n");
printmatrix(a);
printf("a[2][1]-a[1][2]=%d",a[2][1]-a[1][2]);
return 0;
}
```

The output that I got is,

```
Initially...
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

In function...
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
32765 0 0 

In main...
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 9 9 

a[2][1]-a[1][2]=3
```

Also when I tried to pre-increment the array after declaring it in the main function I got the following error.

```
int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
a++;
```

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:28:2: error: lvalue required as increment operand
 a++;
```

Comment: When declaring a function argument as an array, the compiler treats it as a *pointer*. So the argument declaration `int a[][3]` is really `int (*a)[3]`. That's why you can increment it. When you use `++` on a proper array then that's not possible, as arrays can't be "incremented".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot increment an array, that makes no sense. You can increment a pointer. Pointers and arrays are two different things.

> ++a; //what does this do?

This increments a *pointer*, because `a` is a pointer. Although it is declared as `int a[][3]`, it is *not* a 2D array.

*Why is it a pointer and not an array? Because it is a function parameter. A function parameter cannot be an array. You can declare it with square brackets, but it still won't be an array. It means exactly the same thing as `int (*a)[3]` — only if it is a function parameter. In `printmatrix` too. This is important*.

It is a pointer to a 1D array, which is the first element of a 2D array a.k.a. an array of arrays. After the increment takes place, it starts pointing to the *second* element of the same array. If you think of your 2D array as a matrix, it now points to the second row of the matrix. That's what incrementing a pointer does. If it pointed to the `n`th element of an array before, it will point to the `n+1`th element afterwards (and elements of this particular array are 1D arrays, a.k.a. rows).

This makes printing that happens in `printmatrix(a);` *undefined behaviour*. `a` now points to the *second* element of a 2D array, but `printmatrix` has no idea about it, and prints as if there are still 3 rows ahead of it.

> Also when I tried to pre-increment the array after declaring it in the main function I got the following error.

That's right, because in `main`, `a` is an array, not a pointer. You cannot increment an array.

Answer (score 1):

> I have just started learning 2D arrays in C and I came across this
> code where a 2D array is directly pre-incremented like this `++array`.

No, you didn't.  At least not in a program that any C compiler I know would accept.  Arrays often contain modifiable elements, but whole arrays are not modifiable units.

In this function ...

> ```
> int function(int a[][3])
> {
>     int i,j;
>     ++a; //what does this do?
>     printf("In function...\n");
>     printmatrix(a);
>     a[1][1]++;
> }
> ```

... although parameter `a` is expressed using array syntax, it is in fact a pointer, not an array.  This is a quirk of C, though it works out pretty consistently with other C semantics around arrays.  The function signature is equivalent to ...

```
int function(int (*a)[3])
```

..., which declares `a` as a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s.  Thus, the `++a` within has its normal effect: it computes a pointer to the next `int[3]` following `*a` and updates `a` to point to that.

Now consider `main()`:

> ```
> int main()
> {
> int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
> printf("Initially...\n");
> printmatrix(a);
> function(a);
> // [...]
> ```

In `main()`, identifier `a` designates a 2D array, but with a couple of notable exceptions, wherever it appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element.  Such a pointer has exactly the type that `function()` expects for its parameter, so the function call is just fine.

Note well that C function calls have strictly pass-by-value semantics.  The function receives its own copy of that pointer, so changes it makes do not affect the pointer value in `main()` (which has no enduring storage) much less the array from which it was derived.

> Also when I tried to pre-increment the array after declaring it in the
> main function I got the following error.
>
> ```
> int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
> a++;
> ```

As I wrote already, whole arrays are not modifiable.  The diagnostic message produced by your compiler is a bit off, however.  The `a` in that fragment is an lvalue.  But it is not a *modifiable* lvalue, which is what the pre- and post-increment operators require for an operand.